# how to get plain hyperlink text from stored value of ContentControl's Range.WordOpenXML, instead of its syntax value?

Tags: c#, utf-8, vsto, openxml, word-contentcontrol

I have hyperlink in Word's `ContentControl` like below

```
http://www.yahoo.com
```

and I'm storing it's value as below to use it later on

```
var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cc.Range.WordOpenXML));
```

when I decode it again as below and getting its text content as,

```
var decoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encoded));
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(decoded);
string ccText = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("document", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main")).FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

by this I'm getting `HYPERLINK "http://www.yahoo.com/" \o "Follow link"` instead of `http://www.yahoo.com`, expecting `http://www.yahoo.com` as result.

same is the case for email where getting `HYPERLINK "mailto:abc@xyz.com" abc@xyz.com` instead of `abc@xyz.com`

If I'm using `cc.Range.WordOpenXML` in above method to get text content, instead of decoded one, then I'm getting proper value as `http://www.yahoo.com`

When I compared decoded XML with prior to encoded one, It seems like Hyperlink node of XML is getting modified, I think this is the root cause for this issue.

**Original XML before encoding:** retrieved from `doc.Descendants(XName.Get("document", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"))`

```
<w:hyperlink r:id="rId4" w:tooltip="Follow link" w:history="1"> 
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="00E862A6">  
      <w:rPr>   
        <w:rStyle w:val="Hyperlink" />  
      </w:rPr>  
      <w:t>http://www.yahoo.com</w:t>   
    </w:r>  
  </w:hyperlink>
```

**changed XML structure after decoding:**

```
<w:ins w:id="5" w:author="xxxxxx xxxxxx" w:date="2021-03-30T16:42:00Z">
    <w:r>
      <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> HYPERLINK "http://www.yahoo.com/" \o "Follow link" </w:instrText>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
      <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
    </w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="00E862A6">
      <w:rPr>
        <w:rStyle w:val="Hyperlink" />
      </w:rPr>
      <w:t>http://www.yahoo.com</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
      <w:rPr>
        <w:rStyle w:val="Hyperlink" />
      </w:rPr>
      <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
    </w:r>
  </w:ins>
```

Any way to get plain hyperlink text instead of its syntax value, from Word's `ContentControl`'s `Range` stored like above use case? not sure if I'm doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get any solution for this root cause, So until I get way to retrieve valid required text from range without HYPERLINK syntax,

Not a best way or perfect solution, but as workaround for now I removed  `HYPERLINK \"` and `\\o \"Follow link\"` from string to get only `http://www.yahoo.com/` after finding its position in string.

Looking forward to actual solution.